# What do you call an array with identical keys/values?

Tags: php, arrays, terminology

Is there an established term for arrays where each element has a value identical to its key?

Example in PHP:

```
<?php
$array = [
    'foo' => 'foo',
    'bar' => 'bar',
];
?>
```

Comment: maybe call it "pointless"?

Comment: 'Uncommon' is also appropriate I feel :P

Comment: I do not know of a standard name for this. Why would you need this structure?

Comment: It's still an array, technically, but you could probably get away with calling it a "Set", since the only reasonable use I can think of would be checking that an element is in the collection in O(1) time. Other languages have dedicated Set types.

Comment: A term for this specific structure would help e.g. when documenting a function return value, to inform that the returned array can be used with e.g. array_intersect_key().

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's still associative array; but if this is a common trait throughout the array (identical key => value pairs) then you could get away with making it a indexed (serial) array too - why have duplicate data, you know?

Comment: That's how I feel. It's basically wasted memory carrying around extra data. If the value isn't know ahead of time when calling the array, then it's called by a numeric reference, ergo WTF is the key for? Or totally pointless when the value is known ahead of time.